# How to use mid function in Power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

hello help me to use mid function to get the date(October 15 2022) in column1 all rows, from column 33 (AUC as on October 15 2022) in power query.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you want this which pulls the date from the first row in [Column33]

```
   TextDate = Date.FromText( Text.Split( #"PriorStepNameHere"{0}[Column33],"as on "){1}),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "ExtractedDate", each TextDate)
```

EDIT:

try adding a column ... custom column with this code (replacing #"PriorStepNameHere" with your actual prior step name)

```
= Date.FromText( Text.Split( #"PriorStepNameHere"{0}[Column33],"as on "){1})
```

Comment: sir not getting how to use this steps

Comment: edited answer. Try to add the custom column as described.

Comment: sir after adding custom column with this code   = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value3", "taarikh", each Date.FromText( Text.Split( #"Date"{0}[Column33],"as on "){1}))                          ERROR showing in taarikh coloumn.

Comment: You would have to post your code for me to review by editing your answer and pasting from home..advanced editor...